# Why do I get an Error in `contrasts within lapply function?

Tags: r, for-loop

I receive this error:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

when I run through a loop of variables to perform a meta-analysis on. I have run each variable separately through the model and the model runs without errors for each variable. I am assuming that there is a mistake in my loop code. Any help is appreciated!

```
varlist<-as.list(c("population","Per_POV","Per_UNEMP","Per_SNGPRNT","Per_MINORITY","Per_AGE65","Per_AGE17"))

 models <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {
 rma(yi = RERI, 
  sei = SE_RERI, 
  data = meta_analysis, 
  method = "ML", 
  mods = ~ x, 
  test="knha")
 })
```

Comment: Try `mods = ~ get(x)`. The error is because as is `x` is a character string, not a variable. You need to `get` the variable with that name.

Comment: That would imply that, for at least one of the terms you request contrasts, all of the observations in your data have the same (non-missing) value.  But without your input data, I can't be sure...

Comment: Thank you Rui! That worked!